# SQL query, duplicate check based on 4 columns

Tags: mysql

We have a table where we have exchanges rate information for most currencies and new exchange rates are added to the table each month.

The exchange rate information is for the most times duplicate to each other, like so:

[image]

One of our procedures is to extract the information to be put into another system. But, this system checks if there are duplicate values, like the above example. Based on Column 1, 2 and from_date to to_date, there is a duplicate.

I created the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN t1.FROM_CUR<>(CASE WHEN t1.FROM_CUR<t1.TO_CUR THEN t1.FROM_CUR ELSE t1.TO_CUR end) THEN 'wrong register' else 'ok register' end as clase
, t1.FROM_CUR, t1.TO_CUR, 
CAST(t1.EX_RATE as Date) AS FROM_DATE, 
CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD( month, 1, t1.EX_RATE)) as Date) as TO_DATE, 'Corporate' as CORPORATE, t1.EXCH_RATE 

FROM EXCH_RATE t1
JOIN EXCH_RATE t2
ON t1.FROM_CUR = t2.TO_CURAND t1.TO_CUR = t2.FROM_CUR and t1.EX_RATE <> t2.EX_RATE
```

But what this does, it tagging the "unique" row, I still need to put the data in excel and the remove all of the 'wrong register'.

Is there a way to improve this query, so I only get 'ok registers'?

Comment: if you have  FROM_CUR,TO_CUR,FROM_DATE,TO_DATE the same, how do you know which EX_RATE to use?

Comment: Quick question. Based on `FROM_CUR` and `TO_CUR`, the example data is different. The first converts from EURO to USD and the second converts from USD to EURO. Currently 1EURO is 1.16USD. 1USD is 0.86EURO?

Comment: If you create a unique key on the table on fields `(FROM_CUR,TO_CUR,FROM_DATE,TO_DATE)`, and change your loading script to `INSERT IGNORE`, then you'll never have duplicates.

Comment: what will be your distinct result set?

Comment: @danblack does not matter which one it is, adding only EURO -> USD will also create an Inverse Rate from USD - EURO in our target system. In our source table, The exchange rate from one currency to another is the same if we inverse the rate.  Unfortunately, I cannot modify the table (security reasons).

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Having all FROM_CUR as EURO to all of our other currencies is not a problem, or having USD, or AUD or whatever actually. Since in the target system will create a Inverse Rate based on the information from one currency to another.

Answer (score 0):

use case when and make single name and use distinct

```
   select distinct case when from_cur in('usd','euro') then 'usd' end as from_cur,
    case when to_cur in('usd','euro') then 'euro' end as To_cur,from_Date,to_date,rate from t
```

Comment: We have more than 30+ currencies, I don't understand how I would go ahead and add all of them into that solution.

Comment: @Realbunny put all sample data and what want as a output otherwise tough to guide